# How can I update a column of mytable from anothertable based on primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Query, how can I update this table

```
pkey   ColA   ColB   ColC
----   ----   ----   ----
ABC1   appl   pine   orng
BOPQ   pine   appl   orng
PLKQ   orng   appl   pine
```

to get ColC values from this table

```
pkey   ColA   ColB   ColC
----   ----   ----   ----
ABC1   xbcs   qqqq   STRA
BOPQ   asdf   retf   BERR
PLKQ   32q4   xcvv   YTAR
MLAO   iasp   xclk   qppe
```

and get this updated result

```
pkey   ColA   ColB   ColC
----   ----   ----   ----
ABC1   appl   pine   STRA
BOPQ   pine   appl   BERR
PLKQ   orng   appl   YTAR
```

Comment: i only have a few things in mind (like UPDATE and then SET VALUES) but i'm not sure how to do it.. im afraid that our database could get messed up again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more options

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ColC = t2.ColC
FROM dbo.test1 t1 JOIN dbo.test2 t2 ON t1.pkey = t2.pkey
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff230/2/2)

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
update This_table
set This_table.ColA =  C.ColA,
    This_table.ColB =  C.ColB
from ColC C
where C.pkey = This_table.pkey
```